# Perfect Balancing, linear time

Tags: algorithm

How can I rebuild a binary searching tree into perfect balanced in linear time?
I think i'll do rotations to find median, but I'm not sure if its good way.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you can do it in two steps:

1. Extract a sorted array from the tree using in-order traversal.
2. Construct a near-perfect binary tree. For example, by just capping the height with h=log<sub>2</sub>n where n is the number of elements. You will get only a part of the perfect tree if n is not equal to 2<sup>k</sup>-1 for some integer k, but the height will still be minimal possible.

Here is an explanatory image for constructing the tree of values 1, 2, 3, ... 10:

```
           8
    4            10
 2     6        9
1 3   5 7
```

Alternatively, on step 2, you can put the middle element of the array as root, divide what remains into two equally sized parts, and proceed recursively. An example:

```
            5
     2              8
 1       3       7      10
       4       6       9
```

Each of the steps can be performed in linear time.